# Errors ITMS-90022 and ITMS-90023 when delivering APP to AppStore

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I had to update my Xamarin to latest version because in this new version there is a slot on xcassets to put a 1024x1024 icon. Without this icon i can't release my App on TestFlight, but with this new version i can't deliver my app to AppStore. Everytime i try i get these errors:

[image: Errors]

I've already searched in all solutions inside stackoverflow and none of then worked.

Does someone already solved theses errors?

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing icons? If you have and your still getting those errors then try doing a clean and rebuild, finally you can try uploading your app directly from the xcode organizer instead of the application launcher.

Comment: On xcassets there isn't any slot that correspond with these resolutions and inside info.plist didn't work. I will try with xcode organizer.

Comment: It should be listed under iPhone ios 5,6. Check in the attributes inspector that you have it the "iPhone" checkbox selected.

Answer (score 2):

It requires you to provide an icon with dimensions 57x57 and 72x72. The thing is, that is needed only for devices on iOS 7 or earles. There is about 2% of users on that iOS version, so my advice will be to move the minimum iOS version to at least iOS 8. That will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, but where can i put these images, on xcassets there isn't any slot that correspond with these resolutions and  inside info.plist didn't work.